# Get Sim Time in Sfunction (ssGetT)?

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I used ssGetT(S), for some reason doesn't seem to work.
Simple model, is the 'timestwo' with fixed time step 0.01 sec (auto solver)

I call it in the mdlOutput()

```
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    int_T i;
    InputRealPtrsType uPtrs = ssGetInputPortRealSignalPtrs(S,0);
    real_T *y = ssGetOutputPortRealSignal(S,0);
    int_T width = ssGetOutputPortWidth(S,0);

    //for (i=0; i<width; i++) {
    //     *y++ = 2.0 *(*uPtrs[i]);
    //}

    *y = (real_T)ssGetT(S);
}
```

Comment: What is the output? How do you see the output?

Comment: I get zero in the output.  The length of the sim time is 10 seconds

Comment: Some more information is needed. What is this block's sample time? Have you set ssSetInputPortRequiredContiguous to true? Also try changing solver to discrete with fixed step.

Comment: No, this is the timestwo example from matlab. There is no place for ssSetInputPortRequiredContinuous .  I changed the solver to discrete. Still it's zero. Head scratching

Comment: Can you put your whole s-function here and screenshot of model? May be we can try reproducing with that.

Comment: Making that one change to the example code works as expected.  How many inputs to the S-Function do you have?  If you have n inputs then you will have n outputs, but that code change only puts the time into the first output, the other n-1 outputs will be zero.